# batch created C interface in nimlang with template/macro?

Tags: templates, dll, macros, nim-lang

## BackGround

In fact, I am porting [FLTK C 1.3.3 for FreeBASIC](https://www.freebasic.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=24547&sid=7b7d502e6c4871583b6d1d4b2f1aaff1) to [nimlang](http://nimlang.org/). Please note [FLTK C 1.3.3 for FreeBASIC](https://www.freebasic.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=24547&sid=7b7d502e6c4871583b6d1d4b2f1aaff1) is a **C** interface upon the [FLTK in CPP](http://fltk.org/).

Many functions in DLL meet the same similar name format, for example

```
#inclib "fltk-c-1.3.3-64" ' Windows 64-bit

function Fl_ButtonExNew (byval x as long, byval y as long, byval w as long, byval h as long, byval title as const zstring ptr=0) as Fl_ButtonEx Ptr
sub Fl_ButtonExDelete(byval x as Fl_ButtonEx ptr)

function Fl_BoxExNew (byval x as long, byval y as long, byval w as long, byval h as long, byval title as const zstring ptr=0) as Fl_BoxEx Ptr
sub Fl_BoxExDelete(byval x as Fl_BoxEx ptr)

and so on
```

and it seems that the delcared function/sub will load the function of same name in fltk-c-1.3.3-64.dll automatically( correct me if  am wrong)

## Solution in FreeBASIC

So in the FreeBASIC header `fltk-main.bi`, there is an aided macro

```
#macro DeclareEx(_name_)
declare function _name_##ExNew(byval x as long, byval y as long, byval w as long, byval h as long, byval title as const zstring ptr=0) as _name_##Ex ptr
declare sub      _name_##ExDelete         (byref ex as _name_##Ex ptr)
#endmacro
```

by the help of which, the above code( and many other codes) can be generated by a simple one line code:

```
DeclareEx(Fl_Button)
DeclareEx(Fl_Box)
```

## My question in nimlang

In nimlang( please ignore the number type conversion for the time being), the above code can be translated by hand as

```
const fltk = "fltk-c-1.3.3-64.dll"
type long = int64
proc Fl_ButtonExNew (x: long, y: long, w: long, h: long, title: cstring=nil): Ptr Fl_ButtonEx {.cdecl, importc: "Fl_ButtonExNew", dynlib: fltk, discardable.}
proc Fl_ButtonExDelete(x: ptr Fl_ButtonEx) {.cdecl, importc: "Fl_ButtonExDelete", dynlib: fltk, discardable.}

proc Fl_BoxExNew (x: long, y: long, w: long, h: long, title: cstring=nil): Ptr Fl_BoxEx {.cdecl, importc: "Fl_BoxExNew", dynlib: fltk, discardable.}
proc Fl_BoxExDelete(x: ptr Fl_BoxEx) {.cdecl, importc: "Fl_BoxExDelete", dynlib: fltk, discardable.}
```

So I try to mimic what the FreeBASIC Macro does as

```
const fltk = "fltk-c-1.3.3-64.dll"
type long = int64

template DeclareEx*(name: untyped) {.dirty.}=
    type `name Ex` = object
    type `name ExNew`* = proc(x: long, y: long, w: long, h: long, title: cstring=nil): ptr `name Ex` {.cdecl, importc: "name New", dynlib: fltk, discardable.}
    type `name ExDelete`*  = proc(ex: ptr `name Ex`) {.cdecl, importc: "name ExDelete", dynlib: fltk, discardable.}

DeclareEx(Fl_Button)
```

But when I compile it, I get

> d.nim(9, 10) template/generic instantiation of `DeclareEx` from here
>
> d.nim(6, 118) Error: invalid pragma: importc: "name New"

So, any solution? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backticks interpolation offered in templates can be used only in positions where identifiers are expected. The `importc` pragma expects a constant string expression. You can use the `astToStr` magic to convert any AST input to its corresponding string representation and this is the key to the solution here:

```
const fltk = "fltk-c-1.3.3-64.dll"
type long = int64

template DeclareEx*(name: untyped) =
  const
    newProc = astToStr(name) & "New"
    deleteProc = astToStr(name) & "ExDelete"

  type `name Ex`* {.inject.} = object
  proc `name ExNew`*(x: long, y: long, w: long, h: long, title: cstring=nil): ptr `name Ex` {.cdecl, inject, importc: newProc, dynlib: fltk, discardable.}
  proc `name ExDelete`* (ex: ptr `name Ex`) {.cdecl, inject, importc: deleteProc, dynlib: fltk, discardable.}

DeclareEx(Fl_Button)
DeclareEx(Fl_Window)

var btn: ptr Fl_ButtonEx
Fl_ButtonExDelete(btn)
```

Comment: thanks but I can't understand `importc: "x"` the part. How it can be translated into, for example, `importc: "Fl_BoxExNew"`

Comment: Ah, I've missed to make the final modifications to the code. The idea is that I'm passing the new constants to `importc`. The example is fixed now.

Comment: when I use this template more than one times, for example, `DeclareEx(Fl_Button)`, `DeclareEx(Fl_Table)`, I get `Error: redefinition of 'newProc'; previous declaration here: a.nim(6, 5)`. So not-exported `newProc` does not behaves like a local variant in template.

Comment: This can be fixed by writing "proc `name ExNew`*(x: long, y: long, w: long, h: long, title: cstring=nil): ptr `name Ex` {.cdecl, importc: astToStr(name) & "ExNew", dynlib: fltk, discardable.}"; but I prefer to the way in your post(i.e. define the string first before using it, which makes the code clear/short to read), but how can we make `newProc` a local variant? Thanks

Comment: This is because the template is marked as `dirty` (see [hygiene in templates](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#templates-hygiene-in-templates) for an explanation). The issue is solved by marking the constants with the `gensym` pragma.

Comment: sorry but in your code, when I try to make tons of widgets, for example, `DeclareEx(Fl_Button)` then `DeclareEx(Fl_Windows)`, I get `a.nim(6, 5) Error: redefinition of 'newProc'; previous declaration here: a.nim(6, 5)`. I checked https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#templates-hygiene-in-templates which says "inject and gensym have no effect in dirty templates"

Comment: OK, I've modified the code once more to use a regular template instead of a dirty one.

Answer (score 0):

The [importc pragma](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#foreign-function-interface-importc-pragma) is used to import a proc or variable from C. However, you are writing `importc: "name New"`, and `name New` is not a valid identifier in C because it has a space in it. You would need to try to concatenate the symbolic name of the variable you are passing into the template with that additional string suffix.

I don't know how you can do that in a template, though. Maybe you could pass a string as parameter and then use the `&` operator to concatenate it with the suffix for `importc`.